# Determine Location of RiakObject during conflict resolution

Tags: java, riak

I am in the process of migrating my Java code from Riak Client 1.4 to Riak Client 2.0.

I'm storing a `BinaryValue` in Riak 2.0, encapsulated in a `RiakObject`. I need to provide my own `ConflictResolver` to deal with siblings, but in order to do that I need to pull in other data. This data is derived from the key of the stored object.

In Riak 1.4, I used `IRiakObject`, which exposed `getKey()`. `RiakObject` of Riak 2.0 does not offer this.

How is it possible to determine the `Location` (specifically the key) of the object during `ConflictResolver.resolve(List<RiakObject> siblings)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best approach, but it seems to work:

1. Create a POJO as a container for the binary data. Annotate a `String` field with `@RiakKey`:

   ```
   public class Chunk {

       @RiakKey
       public String   chunkId;

       public byte[]   data;
   }
   ```
2. Create a custom converter:

   ```
   import com.basho.riak.client.api.convert.ConversionException;
   import com.basho.riak.client.api.convert.Converter;
   import com.basho.riak.client.core.util.BinaryValue;
   public class ChunkConverter extends Converter<Chunk> {

       public ChunkConverter() {
           super(Chunk.class);
       }

       public Chunk toDomain(BinaryValue val, String contentType) throws ConversionException {
           Chunk chunk = newDomainInstance();
           chunk.data = val.getValue();
       }

       public ContentAndType fromDomain(Chunk chunk) throws ConversionException {
           return new ContentAndType(BinaryValue.unsafeCreate(chunk.data), "application/octet-stream");
       }
   }
   ```
3. Register the converter from #2 for the class from #1:

   ```
   ConverterFactory.getInstance().registerConverterForClass(Chunk.class, new ChunkConverter());
   ```
4. Create a conflict resolver for the class from #1:

   ```
   public class ChunkConflictResolver implements ConflictResolver<Chunk> {

       public Chunk resolve(List<Chunk> siblings) throws UnresolvedConflictException {
           if (siblings == null) {
               return null;
           }
           Chunk oneChunk = siblings.get(0);
           // finally, the key!
           String key = oneChunk.chunkId;
           ...
       }
   }
   ```
5. Register the new conflict resolver from #4 for the class from #1:

   ```
   ConflictResolverFactory.getInstance().registerConflictResolver(Chunk.class, new ChunkResolver());
   ```
6. When fetching the object from Riak, specify the class from #1 as type of value:

   ```
   Location loc = new Location(...);
   FetchValue op = new FetchValue.Builder(loc).build();
   Chunk chunk = riakClient.execute(op).getValue(Chunk.class);
   ```

During the conversion, the context of the object is transferred, observing the [annotations](https://basho.github.io/riak-java-client/2.0.0/com/basho/riak/client/api/annotations/package-tree.html). The custom converter only needs to transfer the value-part of the data.